# It took a huge effort from me

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

can I say "it took a huge effort from me to read this book"?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have in mind some "it" you want to talk about?  Otherwise, do what Alan said: "This book took a huge effort to read."  or "Reading this book took a huge effort from me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **"Huge"** is an overused word and is used to describe too many **"big"** things too many times. lol It's currently flooded communications, et al, due to a certain presiding president. It's colloquial use makes it appear gauche and unrefined. Rather, it's better to use words like **"an immense"** or **"a vast amount of..."**. Secondly, you do not have to say, **"for me"**. It is implied in your statement and the phrasing of your sentence is a bit common. Rather (and especially as a written statement) the sentence should more eloquently be written, **"This book took an immense effort to read."** and if you want to include yourself in this statement, then it should read, **"This book took an immense effort for me to read."**

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer it in active voice instead of passive. So instead of "for me", write:

This book took me an immense effort to read.